# What is the difference between column and row vectors in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

How should I write a vector? as a row or column matrix? 
I ask this question because I see many people including me that writing a vector both ways in linear algebra, but now that I think about it it should not be that way, did ever someone defined it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both $1\times n$ and $n\times 1$ arrays are vectors, the primary difference is that they belong to different spaces of the matrix which are dual to each other... I find it's however most common to denote vectors as columns since we usually use the equation $A x = b$ with right-hand multiplication of a column vector

Answer (score 1):

It's rather arbitrary but it makes sense to restrict yourself to one or the other to avoid confusion. The column vector convention has notational similarities with $f(x)$ notation, which gives the function on the left in the same way we might multiply a column vector on the left by a matrix in the form $Ax$. There is no reason you cannot do all of this backwards though by establishing the row vector and multiplying on the right as $xA$. I would also point out that rows and column vectors are not the only choices you have. For example the space of two by two matrices with coefficients in a field form a vector space over that field as well and is neither a column or row vector. If one form or another is prefered it often has more to do with the linear transformations you intend to apply to the vector and how you want to organize the notation for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you think of a column as a vector, and of a row as a linear map.

Is a convention, but it is pretty convenient, so you should write your vectors as columns.

To answer to a comment :
You can multiply a matrix by a vector on the right : $AX$ (if $A$ is the matrix), and it means you apply the map to the vector.

Comment: But why is it ok to write a vector as a row? lets say I want to multiply a vector by a matrix then if I multiply the matrix by a row vector then it is not defined. right?

Comment: Your answer to my comment seems wrong, see why: take a matrix (2x3) and two copies of the same vector (3x1) and (1x3). one of the vectors you can multiply but the other one you can't. so it means that they are different vectors to me

Comment: By convention, multiplication by a matrix is "on the left", and with matrices, since the multiplication is non-commutative, left isn't the same as right. You get the opposite convention by taking transposes (trading rows for columns, or vice versa), so this isn't an "absolute truth", but one we decided on to avoid confusion. To be more specific, the trasformation $A \mapsto A^T$ is an *isomorphism* when matrices are considered *just as a vector space* but an *anti-isomorphism* when you consider $n\times n$ matrices as an *algebra* (taking matrix multiplication into account).